# Robolectric using Navigation Architecture Component,Resources$NotFoundException: nav_graph

Tags: android, android-testing, robolectric, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

I am getting trouble to run robolectric test in android

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

I am using Navigation Architecture Component
I am getting view inflation exception

below is my error log

```
 android.view.InflateException: XML file       C:\Users\StudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\merged-not-compiled-resources\debug\layout\activity_main.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): XML file C:\Users\StudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\merged-not-compiled-resources\debug\layout\activity_main.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class fragment Caused by: android.view.InflateException: XML file C:\Users\jitendrakumar\StudioProjects\app\build\intermediates\merged-not-compiled-resources\debug\layout\activity_main.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class fragment
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: packagename:navigation/nav_graph
            at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLegacyAssetManager.loadXmlResourceParser(ShadowLegacyAssetManager.java:591)
            at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.loadXmlResourceParser(ShadowResources.java:205)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getXml(Resources.java:1206)
            at androidx.navigation.NavInflater.inflate(NavInflater.java:67)
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:424)
            at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:406)
            at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:226)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
```

I already enabled

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch Your root element id in navigation.xml file (or your custom res/navigation/*.xml). ID must be "@+id/nav_graph". Example:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/homeDestinationFragment">
```